# Salesforce Lightning Component issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working on Lightning Component but ran into an issue, my error is below in attached image.[image]

I believe the issue is in the helper.js of the component.
Can anyone help me out in this issue, my helper.js code is below.

```
({
subscribe : function(component, event, helper) {
    //console.log("Subscribe function called");
    var empApi = component.find("empApi");
    var channel = component.get("v.channelName");
    var replayId = -1;
    var callback = function (message) {
        /*
        console.log("Received [" + message.channel +
                    " : " + message.data.event.replayId + "] payload=" +
                    JSON.stringify(message.data.payload)
                   );
        */

    /* Extracting payload, userId and username from the message
     * and setting the attributes accordingly
     */    
        var payload=JSON.stringify(message.data.payload);
        var s=payload.substring(1);
        s=s.substring(0,s.length-1);
        var i=s.indexOf('`');
        var message=s.substring(0,i);
        var FromUserid=s.substring(i+1,i+19);
        var FromUserName=s.substring(i+19);

        if(!component.get("v.isChatActive")){
            component.set("v.isChatActive",true);
            component.set("v.selectedUserId",FromUserid);
            component.set("v.selectedUserName",FromUserName);
        }

        //Calling helper method to push the message to the chat window
        this.handleInboundMessage(component, event, message);
    }.bind(this);

    var errorHandler = function (message) {
                console.log("Received error ", JSON.stringify(message) );
            }.bind(this);
    empApi.onError(errorHandler);

    var sub;
    empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, callback).then(function(value) {
        console.log("Subscribed to channel " + channel);
        sub = value;
        component.set("v.sub", sub);
        component.set("v.isSubscribed",true);

    });
},
unsubscribe : function(component, event, helper) {
    //console.log("Unsubscribe function called");

    var empApi = component.find("empApi");
    var channel = component.get("v.channelName");
    var callback = function (message) {
        console.log("Unsubscribed from channel " + channel);
    }.bind(this);

    var errorHandler = function (message) {
        console.log("Received error ", message);
    }.bind(this);

    var sub = {"id": component.get("v.sub")["id"],
                "channel": component.get("v.sub")["channel"]};

    empApi.onError(errorHandler);
    empApi.unsubscribe(sub, callback);
    component.set("v.isSubscribed",false);
    component.set("v.showChatBox",false);
},
getOnlineUsers :  function(component, event){
    //console.log('getOnlineUsers  called');
    var action=component.get("c.getOnlineUsers");
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        if(response.getState()==='SUCCESS'){ 
            //console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.UserList",response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else
           console.log(response.getState()); 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
handleInboundMessage : function(component, event, message){
    //console.log('Incoming message');
    component.set("v.showChatBox",true);

    var ul = document.getElementById("ChatList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("class","slds-chat-listitem slds-chat-listitem_inbound");
    li.innerHTML ='<div class="slds-chat-message">'+
                          '<div class="slds-chat-message__body">'+
                                 '<div class="slds-chat-message__text slds-chat-message__text_inbound">'+
                                     '<span>'+message+'</span>'+
                                 '</div>'+
                           '</div>'+
                      '</div>';
    ul.appendChild(li);
},
    /* Pushing the sent message to chat window */
handleOutboundMessage : function(component, event, message){
    //console.log('Outbound message');
    var ul = document.getElementById("ChatList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("class","slds-chat-listitem slds-chat-listitem_outbound");
    li.innerHTML ='<div class="slds-chat-message">'+
                         '<div class="slds-chat-message__body">'+
                                 '<div class="slds-chat-message__text slds-chat-message__text_outbound">'+
                                     '<span>'+message+'</span>'+
                                 '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                       '</div>';
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
})
```

Comment: The problem is in your controller (`...$controller$...`). We can't help you with the code you've posted.

Comment: Open the browser dev tools, switch to source tab, open ChatComponent and here add debugger and try to execute line by line you will surely get your answer.